# Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob `application/pdf': No such file or directory

Tags: php, imagick

I want to convert the PDF to JPG by using imagick, but after I press submit it keeps showing a fatal error: uncaught imagick error. Do you guys know if this is code problem or an imagick extension problem?

[image: Error]

[image: Code]

Comment: do you have a directory named application/pdf ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Comment: Please paste the error message and your code snippet as text in your question.

Comment: @NID yes ,i have the application/pdf..i actually done the upload stuff just i trying to do when submit the button only convert the pdf to jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] stores the MIME type and you are assigning it to the variable $pdf_file and you are trying to read this with imagick. This can't work. You could var_dump($_FILES) and see if you can find the actual file in there.